# triple boot to Windows without loosing xubuntu and kali linux

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, lenovo

I am using a Lenovo laptop I removed Windows and using Xubuntu `xfce` and Kali Linux on my system for many years. I have enough free space on my disk to reinstall Windows. Since I don't have Windows installation media but I have Windows recovery ISO. How I can install Windows without loosing other Operating Systems on my system?

Comment: @zahedae you can Install your Windows then you can `update-grub`from Ubuntu Live cd

Comment: @Mudit will I loose my data on the both Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Well temporary you will lose access to other (l)unix based os as the windows installation does not have a 'do not install bootloader' option. After the installation you will have to boot a livecd and install boot-repair from with a ppa or preferably use this image which has the software pre-installed [boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files) and then quoting from the homesite:

(1) Then burn it on a live-USB key via Rufus or Unetbootin. (do not burn it on CD/DVD if your PC came with Windows8)

(2) Insert the Boot-Repair-Disk and reboot the PC,

(3) Choose your language,

(4) Connect internet if possible

(5) Click "Recommended repair"

(6) Reboot the pc --> solves the majority of bootsector/GRUB/MBR problems